# Extract data from the last row of gridview in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, gridviewrow

I know how to to do it and put the data on textbox when I select a row from a gridview, What I want to achieve now is when I open a modal pop up form containing a gridview, it will automatically select or extract the date column from the last row of gridview.

This is for the purpose of determining the last date from the record.

Here's what I got so far (under click event for button "ADD")

```
   if (grdSpecificTenantRental.Rows.Count == 0)
   {
        txtdatefrom.Text = "No record yet";
    }
else
    {
        GridViewRow  rowtwo = grdSpecificTenantRental.Rows[grdSpecificTenantRental.Rows.Count - 1];

      string index = rowtwo.Cells.ToString();

         txtdatefrom.Text = index;
      }
```

Here's the output int he textbox: System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCellCollection

Obviously this line is incorrect: string index = rowtwo.Cells.ToString();

I want to extract the 4th column in the last row which is the end date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are getting all the cells that is `CellCollection` so if you want to get perticular column value then use that array's index to get the required columns value.As you mentioned 4th columns so use the `index` 3 because index starts from 0.You might want to access it like this,

```
txtDateFrom.Text = grdSpecificTenantRental.Rows[grdSpecificTenantRental.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3].Text;
```

Comment: I've done it and it is no good, same output being displayed in the textbox - System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell

Comment: Did you use the `.text` proerty of the Cells[3].Text.

Comment: IT IS WORKING NOW. my fault, instead of .Text i used .ToString(). Thanks.

Comment: How funny, I have tried the same code earlier but it didn't work. Maybe i just input an incorrent sytax. Thanks though!